Interpreting opposite signs and control/treatment in ACME and ADE in mediation analysis
I have a few questions regarding the interpretation of mediation analysis using the mediation library in R. I'm new to this kind of analysis and I'm having a hard time interpreting them in light of the results of the regressions I've made in order to analyze the impact of my variables. Specifically, ACME values seems to not reflect the regression results, and have opposite signs with the ADE.
I'm studying how two different conditions impacted the DV (values ranging from 0 to 1). My model is this:
model_1 <- lmer(DV ~  conditions + (1|participant), REML=FALSE, data = df)
Where conditions has three factors: control, treat1 and treat2. I have the following results:
 Groups      Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 0.0001166 0.01080 
 Residual                0.0096284 0.09812 
Number of obs: 576, groups:  participant, 96

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   0.505892   0.007167   70.59
treat1       -0.105241   0.010015  -10.51
treat2        0.131336   0.010015   13.11

As seen, both treatments have significant effects in the DV when compared to the baseline. However, I have a variable that seems to be mediating the effects of the conditions. So I've tested the following models:
a)
med_1 <- lmer(med ~ conditions + (1| participant), REML=FALSE, data=data_salience)

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  -0.0089953  0.0009664  -9.308
treat1       -0.0163248  0.0013667 -11.944
treat2        0.1083085  0.0013667  79.246

b)
med_2 <- lmer(DV ~  conditions * med + (1|participant), REML=FALSE, data=data_salience)

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                 0.514882   0.007725  66.651
treat1                     -0.245319   0.018715 -13.108
treat2                      0.280460   0.050689   5.533
med                         0.999477   0.405686   2.464
treat1:med                 -6.176673   0.746400  -8.275
treat2:med                 -2.591555   0.644274  -4.022

I've used an interaction term given that, as shown, it seems that the med variable varies among the conditions. Given these models, I've ran a mediation analysis using the mediate function in R, as such:
med_treat1 <- mediate(med_1, med_2, 
                      treat = "conditions", mediator = "med", 
                      boot = FALSE, sims = 1000,
                      control.value = "control", treat.value ="treat1")

Output Based on Overall Averages Across Groups 

                         Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME (control)            -0.0159      -0.0285         0.00   0.016 *  
ACME (treated)             0.0843       0.0604         0.11  <2e-16 ***
ADE (control)             -0.1896      -0.2211        -0.16  <2e-16 ***
ADE (treated)             -0.0894      -0.1151        -0.06  <2e-16 ***
Total Effect              -0.1053      -0.1271        -0.08  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (control)   0.1538       0.0268         0.29   0.016 *  
Prop. Mediated (treated)  -0.7944      -1.1729        -0.53  <2e-16 ***
ACME (average)             0.0342       0.0216         0.05  <2e-16 ***
ADE (average)             -0.1395      -0.1649        -0.12  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (average)  -0.3203      -0.4874        -0.20  <2e-16 ***


med_treat2 <- mediate(med_1, med_2, 
                      treat = "conditions", mediator = "med", 
                      boot = FALSE, sims = 1000,
                      control.value = "control", treat.value ="treat2")

                         Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME (control)             0.1063       0.0238         0.19   0.012 *  
ACME (treated)            -0.1758      -0.2805        -0.07  <2e-16 ***
ADE (control)              0.3070       0.2001         0.41  <2e-16 ***
ADE (treated)              0.0249      -0.0637         0.11   0.580    
Total Effect               0.1312       0.1121         0.15  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (control)   0.8032       0.1736         1.49   0.012 *  
Prop. Mediated (treated)  -1.3467      -2.1962        -0.55  <2e-16 ***
ACME (average)            -0.0348      -0.1012         0.04   0.308    
ADE (average)              0.1659       0.0960         0.24  <2e-16 ***
Prop. Mediated (average)  -0.2718      -0.7768         0.27   0.308    


A couple of questions:

I don't understand why the mediation analysis gives an ACME and ADE for both control and treatment when using an interaction term in the model. I've read the documentation but I still can't grasp the concept.

The mediator variable was predicted by the conditions variable in the same direction that the DV was predicted by conditions: comparing to the baseline, treat1 had a negative effect both for the DV and for the mediator, while treat2 had a positive effect in both variables. In the interaction term for med:treat2, we see a negative effect. For the mediation analysis with treat1, the ACME (treated) is positive. The ADE is negative, following the logic in the regressions. So it seems that although in the regressions treat1 had a negative effect in the med variable, and the interaction between med and treat1 was also negative, in the mediation analysis the indirect effect is positive. Overall, the total effect is still negative, which in my interpretation shows that the mediation is not that strong after all. However, I'm having a hard time with the logic here. The same goes for the mediation analysis with treat2. The direct effect and the ACME have different signs, showing an opposite movement. Am I missing something here?

I have values greater than 1 in the Proportion Mediated in in treat2. I've read in a post an explanation saying that this is because the mediation effect is greater than the total effect, which can be seen given that the ADE is non-significant. However, ACME average is non-significant while ADE is. I believe I'm not understanding how the function deals with both the control x treatment values and the average.


Thank you!
